# Sitecore Exception Handling and Logging

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

Quiet new newbie to sitecore, I have been reading a lots of blog post from John West regarding sitecore logging and exception handling.

From what I read from sitecore documentation, the exception handling and logging is provided out of box. However, I can lots of people writing blog on including pipeline etc for exception handling and logging.

Could someone please clarify, whether when and why we need to write pipeline for Sitecore using MVC?

Answer (score 3):

Sitecore has its own built-in logging (`Sitecore.Diagnostics` namespace) that it uses itself, however you can also write to the Sitecore logs in your own components. So if you develop some front-end site layouts and modules (user controls or web controls), you can also write to the Sitecore log, e.g.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    // do your stuff, like loading content...
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
    Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Error("Error in ComponentX", ex, this);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yep, understood. But, I was more of curious/concern about why and when do we need to do override mvc.exception pipeline processor, mvc.renderRendering pipeline etc per blog below:
http://www.sitecore.net/nederland/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2012/09/Handling-Exceptions-Globally-in-MVC-Solutions-Using-the-Sitecore-ASPNET-CMS.aspx

Comment: Is your interest in exception handling and logging purely related to Sitecore MVC?

The article you linked to relates to an old Technology Preview release of Sitecore 6.6, the latest release is Sitecore 6.6 Update 3.

Comment: Yep, I'm interested on latest release of sitecore MVC? Do we neeed to worry about all those points specified on blog or just do try catch where ever it makes sense?